# $\operatorname{lcm}(a, b, c) = 100$ What are all the triads $a, b, c $ that happen? lcm-least common multiple

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

$$\operatorname{lcm}(a, b, c) = 100$$

What are all the triads $a, b, c $ that happen?

How many answers are there?

We've the canonical form $100=2^2 \cdot 5^2$ therefore $\tau(100)=9$ Assuming $a,b,c $ to be distinct integers there are $\binom{18}{3}$ tuples $(a,b,c)$ satisfying the desired conditions
Sidenote : OP must specify the nature of $a,b,c$, i.e. whether $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$or $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and whether they're all distinct or not  ???   or  I think the answer is $\binom{3}{1}^2 \cdot 9^2 $.

Who knows if it is right or not please help prove the solution ?

Comment: Could you detail how you get $\tau(100)=9$ ?

Comment: $100=2^2\cdot 5^2 ~ \tau(100)=(2+1)(2+1)=3\cdot3=9$

Comment: You have proposed two answers to the question.  What is the logic behind them?  Which do you believe?  Yes, you need to define whether negative numbers are allowed.  That increases the number of solutions.  Normally we would insist that all the numbers be positve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ordered triples of nonnegative integers less than or equal to $2$ with at least one coordinate equal to $2$ (and hence having a maximum of $2$) is $3^3-2^3=27-8=19$ (all ordered triples, minus those with all coordinates less than $2$).

Hence, since LCMs are all about taking the maximum of the exponents of each prime factor (and likewise, the minimum for the GCD), the answer is $19^2=361$, assuming that only solutions with $a, b,$ and $c$ all positive are allowed. If one allows at least one of $a, b,$ and $c$ to be negative, then one must multiply the answer by $8$ to get $361 \cdot 8=2888$.